# Не включается .so на PHP

Tags: php, apache, debian, модули

Видимо я чего-то не понимаю, пытаюсь установить [skein](https://github.com/jedisct1/PHP-Skein-Hash), устанавливаю все как надо, файл .so добавляется в папку с расширениями, уже во всех php.ini прописал

```
extension_dir=/usr/lib/php5/20100525
extension=skein.so
```

но PHP все равно его не подключает. В phpinfo показывается правильный php.ini и правильный extension_dir, но расширение вообще не замечает.
До этого устанавливал точно так же, но включал его через ISPManager. Сейчас же, после переустановки PHP, надо включить его вручную.

**upd:** причем если вписать в консоли `php -m > mod.txt` то в `mod.txt` будет прописал skein, но в phpinfo его нет.

**upd2:** как оказалось при `php -v` выдает данные старого PHP, и в ISPManager высвечивается название старого PHP, но при этом в phpinfo новая версия.

Comment: а файл `/usr/lib/php5/20100525/skein.so` имеется?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin само собой. Подозреваю что при компиляции PHP не указал какие то важные для Apache/ISPManager пути, но все же странно что расширение не подключается.

Comment: надеюсь, о просмотре логов после перезагрузки apache напоминать тоже не стоит?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin если имеется в виду "/var/log/apache2/error.log", то там пусто.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Если ввести в консоли команду "php -m > mod.txt", то выдает "PHP Warning:  Module 'skein' already loaded in Unknown on line 0"

Comment: @alexanderbarakin оставил строчки выше только в одном php.ini, ошибка по "php -m > mod.txt" исчезла, но расширение так и не подключилось.

Comment: А apache точно тот PHP использует? Каким образом Apache рестартите?

Comment: @MichaelSivolobov ну в системе только один PHP. Через phpinfo показывает свежее время сборки. Рестарт делают через перезагрузку сервера в ISPManager.

Comment: @MichaelSivolobov Хотя по `php -v` выдает другие данные. Разве возможно что после переустановки остался старый PHP? Или это просто ISPManager не обновил данные..

Comment: Все в этом мире возможно. Посмотрите, какой PHP подключен к Apache. `phpinfo()` смотрите через тот же Apache? Веб-серверов (не только апач) может тоже быть куча настроена.

Comment: Возьмите чистую vps без ISP Manager

Comment: @MichaelSivolobov Система почти полностью настроена по дефолту ISPManager, так что насколько я понимаю в системе только один Apache и больше ничего, хотя могу ошибаться. Не подскажешь какой командой посмотреть какой php подключен к Apache?

Comment: @MichaelSivolobov к слову, у меня в системе отсутствует `httpd.conf` - это может быть причиной?

Comment: `ps -ef | grep apache` (или httpd) потом на найденном апаче запускаешь его с опцией `-V`, он тебе скажет, где конфиг лежит. Там посмотришь, откуда берется PHP, именно у того PHP спросишь, где лежит его `ini` через опцию `--ini`.

Comment: @MichaelSivolobov Странно, в конфиге `apache2.conf` вообще нет ни одного слова "php". При этом если добавить в него `LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so` и перезапустить, то говорит что PHP уже подключен и эта строка пропускается. Буду копаться в файлах, видно ISPManager кучу переадресаций понаделал..

Comment: в конфиге можно найти другие конфиги, которые подключаются. Даже папки могут просматриваться на подключение всех конфигов в конкретной папке

Comment: @MichaelSivolobov В общем проблема явно не моего уровня. В файле `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.load` прописано  `LoadModule php5_module  /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so `, что правильно, в системе только один `libphp5.so`, и дата его измения 13-е число, т.е. это файл нового PHP. Но почему в консоли он выдает данные старого PHP, который датирован 10-м числом, вообще понять не могу. Что старый, что новый PHP подхватывает один и тот же `php.ini`.

Comment: Можно поднять кучу инстансов PHP, которые будут работать от одного конфига. Посмотреть, откуда берется PHP в консоли можно через `which php`.

Comment: @MichaelSivolobov Так суть в том что подхватывается правильный `extension_dir` (по умолчанию в phpinfo другой путь выдает) из `php.ini`, но вот модуль skein не подхватывается.. получается на сайте работает новый PHP но без skein, а в консоли старый PHP и с skein. По пути из `which php` лежит файл `php5` датированный 9 сентября, хотя систему я недавно переустанавливал. В общем чувствую мне будет проще, что бы не терять время, найти библиотеку PHP для генерации 1024 битного хэша.